# What's the deal with this character's eyes?

Tags: the-x-files, x-files-tv-miniseries

In the X-Files episode 11x04, "The Lost Art of Forehead Sweat", at one point

> Mulder meets Dr. They

amidst the [*A-maze-ing Laughter* installation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-maze-ing_Laughter) in Vancouver.

The latter's eyes are surrounded by something that looks like red bruises. Current photos show that the character's actor,

> [Stuart Margolin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0546765/)

, does not generally sport that condition. At the same time, the same character, during flashbacks earlier in the episode, does not seem to have the same feature, either (at least it is not that pronounced).

**What was the meaning or intention behind presenting the character's eyes like that?**

Comment: For reference; https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/V7zuwScIL9Z3UxoEfUFNGA--~A/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjtzbT0xO3c9MTMwMDtoPTE5NTA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en/homerun/feed_manager_auto_publish_494/1782535119b7b0c34f71f0fddc310e35

Comment: @Valorum: Thanks - maybe the [same still on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0546765/mediaviewer/rm2871283712) even comes with a more stable URL.

Comment: Perhaps an implied connection to Reggie, who was hit over the head with a shovel? Or to the domino mask?

Comment: @AaronGullison: These two references appear rather random (and frankly, I do not even see the connection to the first one). Is there anything in particular that makes you think either of those two could be referenced?

Comment: Ecchymosis is a bruising of the skin usually seen near the eyes (called raccoon eyes) sometimes seen in older people and can be caused by a blow to the head. It could be deliberate for the character or simply something that happened and the director decided to go with it.